# Need to get ID of inserted object during Persist execution

Tags: acumatica

I have a (new) header with details and I want to allow the user to insert a (new) header and details at the same time, without first requiring the user to save the header before adding any details. How do I get the value of the header's ID so that I may update the detail rows with that header's ID value before they are saved to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended approach is to decorate foreign key in the detail DAC with **PXDBDefaultAttribute**. The **PXDBDefaultAttribute** subscribes to *RowPersisted handler raised for the header record* to retrieve the header's ID right after the record has been inserted into DB and while the transaction is still open. It also subscribes to *RowPersisting for the detail record* to update foreign key with the value retrieved within the header record RowPersisted handler.